# C2DM confirmation e-mail but no id

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm

I've received a confirmation e-mail after the registration of my Android app on this address http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html. But i've not the registration id. How do i get this registration id, if it's not by subscribing on this page ? Or maybe, I have to wait longer ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U wont get any registration id in your mail. U need to do those things in the client application. The registration id will be unique for the device which the google will assign. That may also changes periodically(refreshed by the google). Go through this link [C2DM article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html). So that u can get a clear picture of the C2DM.

Comment: Welcome Gen. U can get a clear idea of the C2DM from that article, Proceed.. Cheers. :)

Comment: I have another problem with the tutorial you send. Everything work fine, but when I send a message from the serverSimulator I have an InvalidRegistration Exception. I don't understand because i've received the confirmation e-mail for my sender Id.

Comment: @Gen: There u can see the hardcoded registration ID, In tat place. Give the regid which u got.